# Why doesn't the search bar weigh question titles very heavily?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

A search is done when you type in the title of your new question, then click on the textarea to type the body of the question. I've found this search to be infinitely more helpful than the search bar. I believe the ask-question search just uses the titles of the questions. I don't know what the search bar uses but it usually isn't as helpful. I find myself hitting the ask question button so I could use it to do a search. Could we offer a way to use that search, as well as the search bar? Maybe an advanced search. Being able to search through the questions is an imperative feature. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few recent changes in search..

1. Search now *HEAVILY* weights title in the results, since people seemed to really like that approach (used on the /ask page, which searched exclusively on title alone).
2. Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches. So if you enter

   > c++ entities

   it will convert to

   > [c++] entities

automagically.

Try again and see if it is more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Not that well. Instead, you should search with google:

site:stackoverflow.com search items here

Searching with tags:

site:stackoverflow.com inurl:questions/tagged/feature-request search terms

Searching multiple tags:

site:stackoverflow.com inurl:questions/tagged/php+mysql search terms